# `EPERM` on `pidfd_getfd` with socket

Tags: linux, rust

I want to transfer a socket between 2 unrelated processes.

Process 1 creates and listens on the socket, it then attaches shared memory and stores the socket file descriptor in this shared memory and awaits on signal `SIGUSR1`.

Process 2 attaches to the shared, attempts to transfer the file descriptor, then sends the signal `SIGUSR1`.

On calling [`pidfd_getfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_getfd.2.html) in process 2, I get the error `EPERM`.

##### Process 1 output

```
fd: Data { socket: 3, pid: Pid(167046) }
```

##### Process 2 output

```
fd: Data { socket: 3, pid: Pid(167046) }
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: EPERM', src/bin/receive.rs:44:74
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

#### Process 1

```rust
use std::os::fd::{AsRawFd, RawFd};

use nix::fcntl;
use nix::sys::{
    mman, signal,
    socket::{self, SockaddrLike},
};
use nix::unistd::{ftruncate, Pid};

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Data {
    socket: RawFd,
    pid: Pid,
}

const PATH: &str = "/some_arbitrary_path_3";

fn main() {
    // Create a TCP socket listening on localhost:8080
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    let socket = socket::socket(
        socket::AddressFamily::Inet6,
        socket::SockType::Stream,
        socket::SockFlag::empty(),
        None,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let local_host = libc::in6_addr {
        s6_addr: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    };
    let addr = libc::sockaddr_in6 {
        sin6_family: u16::try_from(libc::AF_INET6).unwrap(),
        sin6_port: 8765,
        sin6_flowinfo: u32::default(),
        sin6_addr: local_host,
        sin6_scope_id: u32::default(),
    };
    let addr = unsafe {
        socket::SockaddrIn6::from_raw(
            std::ptr::addr_of!(addr).cast(),
            Some(u32::try_from(std::mem::size_of::<libc::sockaddr_in6>()).unwrap()),
        )
        .unwrap()
    };

    socket::bind(socket, &addr).unwrap();

    socket::listen(socket, 64).unwrap();

    // Store socket file descriptor in shared memory
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    let shared_memory_object = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(
        mman::shm_open(
            PATH,
            fcntl::OFlag::O_RDWR | fcntl::OFlag::O_CREAT | fcntl::OFlag::O_EXCL,
            // TODO: Restrict these to minimum (likely read+write group)
            // Uses full permissions
            nix::sys::stat::Mode::all(),
        )
        .unwrap(),
    );

    let length = std::mem::size_of::<Data>();
    ftruncate(shared_memory_object.as_raw_fd(), length as i64).unwrap();
    let mapped_shared_memory = unsafe {
        mman::mmap(
            None,
            std::num::NonZeroUsize::new(length).unwrap(),
            mman::ProtFlags::PROT_WRITE | mman::ProtFlags::PROT_READ,
            mman::MapFlags::MAP_SHARED,
            Some(&*shared_memory_object),
            0,
        )
        .unwrap()
    };

    let ptr = mapped_shared_memory.cast::<Data>();
    let pid = Pid::this();
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::write(ptr, Data { socket, pid });
    }
    println!("fd: {:?}", unsafe { &*ptr });

    // Await SIGUSR1
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    let mut sigset = signal::SigSet::empty();
    sigset.add(signal::Signal::SIGUSR1);
    sigset.wait().unwrap();
}
```

#### Process 2

```rust
use std::os::fd::AsRawFd;
use std::os::fd::RawFd;

use nix::fcntl;
use nix::sys::{mman, pidfd, signal::Signal};
use nix::unistd::Pid;

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Data {
    socket: RawFd,
    pid: Pid,
}

const PATH: &str = "/some_arbitrary_path_3";

fn main() {
    // Get shared memory object.
    let shared_memory_object = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(
        mman::shm_open(PATH, fcntl::OFlag::O_RDWR, nix::sys::stat::Mode::all()).unwrap(),
    );

    let length = std::mem::size_of::<Data>();
    // Map shared memory.
    let mapped_shared_memory = unsafe {
        mman::mmap(
            None,
            std::num::NonZeroUsize::new(length).unwrap(),
            mman::ProtFlags::PROT_WRITE | mman::ProtFlags::PROT_READ,
            mman::MapFlags::MAP_SHARED,
            Some(&*shared_memory_object),
            0,
        )
        .unwrap()
    };

    // Read data.
    let ptr = mapped_shared_memory.cast::<Data>();
    let data = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
    println!("fd: {:?}", data);

    // Transfer socket file descriptor.
    let pid_fd = pidfd::pid_open(data.pid, false).unwrap();
    let new_socket = pidfd::pidfd_getfd(pid_fd.as_raw_fd(), data.socket).unwrap();
    data.socket = new_socket.as_raw_fd();

    // Send SIGUSR1
    pidfd::pidfd_send_signal(pid_fd, Signal::SIGUSR1, None).unwrap();
}
```

#### Dependencies

The dependencies I'm using here are:

```ini
nix = { git = "https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/nix", rev = "747b7abf9e2dd57d6e52b7d9288f836780f0ec15" }
libc = "0.2.139" # https://crates.io/crates/libc/0.2.139
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to circumvent this.

1. Run the process as privileged (e.g. `sudo`).
2. Use `ptrace` in the ancestor to give the successor permissions. While this can work, it is very tricky and it is using an extremely over-complicated tool for what we are doing here.
3. Send the file descriptor over a UDS (Unix Domain Socket), this works, but sending file descriptors over a UDS is ugly.
4. Enable the `SO_REUSEPORT` option on the socket such that the new process can use the socket without needing to transfer the file descriptor. This is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [`man 2 pidfd_getfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_getfd.2.html),
the use of `pidfd_getfd()` is governed by a `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS` permissions check.
This in turn requires the `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH` check to be passed, which is the check which is used to attach to another process using `ptrace`.
Both checks are described in [`man 2 ptrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html).

In order to be allowed to attach to another process, it used to be enough for the process attaching to the other process (the tracer), to have the same uid as that of the process being acted upon (the tracee).
Nowadays, there is the [Yama security module](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/LSM/Yama.rst), which by default has stricter rules.
If you run process 1 and process 2 as the same user, and `pidfd_getfd()` still results in `EPERM`, it is probably the Yama security module which is disallowing the operation.

For the default value for `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, the behaviour is described as follows in [`man 2 ptrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> 1 ("restricted ptrace") [default value]
> When performing an operation that requires a PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH check, the
> calling process must either have the CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability in the
> user namespace of the target process or it must have a predefined
> relationship with the target process. By default, the predefined relationship
> is that the target process must be a descendant of the caller.
>
> A target process can employ the prctl(2) PR_SET_PTRACER operation to declare
> an additional PID that is allowed to perform PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH operations on
> the target.

You can revert to the old (less secure) behaviour by writing `0` to `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`.

That said, grabbing file descriptors from other processes is conceptually undesirable, as it hinders reasoning about the correctness of a program when the owner of a resource is not in control of it.
Arguably, `pidfd_getfd()` should not be used in normal operations between cooperating processes, but only for programs which manipulate processes themselves, such as debuggers, tracing tools, and implementations of process checkpointing.
The fact that its use is tied to ptrace permissions indicates that it was indeed designed as such.

If you need to share file descriptors between processes, and inheriting them from a parent to a child process is not an option, the proper — though cumbersome — solution would be to send them over UNIX domain sockets.
See the section about SCM_RIGHTS in [`man 7 unix`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), and [`man 3 cmsg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) for a C example.

Compared to `pidfd_getfd()`, which is Linux-specific, this is also a more portable solution.